# extras RollingFileAppender not creating a file

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, logging, log4j

I have reviewed other related questions but have not found a answer for this.  It seems the javadocs at https://logging.apache.org/log4j/extras/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/rolling/RollingFileAppender.html are incorrect and/or incomplete.  At least the  element looks to have a spurious double quote mark in it.
I am starting up in debug mode and it all looks OK.  Yet, I cannot find the log file.  We have other custom appenders that are working fine but I am trying to replace them with the OTB solution.
Here is my config:

```
  <appender name="file" class="org.apache.log4j.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <param name="threshold" value="debug" />
    <rollingPolicy name="file" class="org.apache.log4j.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
      <param name="FileNamePattern" value="logs/My_Server.%d{yyyy-MM-dd-hh}.log"/>
    </rollingPolicy>
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
      <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{ISO8601} %r [%t] %-5p %c{1} %x - %m%n"/>
    </layout>
  </appender>

  <appender name="ASYNCfile" class="org.apache.log4j.AsyncAppender">
    <param name="BufferSize" value="500"/>
    <param name="blocking" value="false"/>
    <appender-ref ref="file"/>
  </appender>

 <root>
    <priority value="INFO"/>
    <appender-ref ref="ASYNCfile"/>
    <appender-ref ref="console"/>
  </root>
```

And the debug console:

```
log4j: Attaching appender named [file] to appender named [ASYNCfile].
log4j: Class name: [org.apache.log4j.rolling.RollingFileAppender]
log4j: Setting property [threshold] to [DEBUG].
log4j: Setting property [fileNamePattern] to [logs/My_Server.%d{yyyy-MM-dd-hh}.log].
log4j: Parsing layout of class: "org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout"
log4j: Setting property [conversionPattern] to [%d{ISO8601} %r [%t] %-5p %c{1} %x - %m%n].
log4j: setFile called: logs/My_Server.2017-07-17-05.log, true
log4j: setFile ended
```

I don't see any errors related to this in the console ouput - there is just no file to be found.

Comment: Actually, I just searched my hard drive and located the log files in an unexpected location.  They are in the Eclipse installation directory.  I am running tomcat and other appenders are writing logs into the tomcat runtime folder that Eclipse creates when you add a server.  Now I need to track down why they are writing into two different locations when I have not specified anything that I am aware of.  (Others have configured log4j before me...)

Comment: Other related posts point at that the FileNamePattern value should be an absolute path.  At least then there will be no confusion over where the file will be.  The Javadocs don't describe handling of this value when it is relative.  The best advice may be to use ${catalina.base}/logs/yourFileNamepattern.  Hopefully this post will be helpful to others.  Also use the log4j configuration debug=true flag to help troubleshoot.